# Calculate the difference between 2 SQLite datetimes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, datetime

I'm have a startDate and a endDate stored in a SQLite database and need to calculate the difference in minutes and seconds between the 2 datetimes using javascript.

For example:

```
startDate = 2012-10-07 11:01:13
endDate = 2012-10-07 12:42:13
```

I've had a good read though loads of similar questions on SO but could only find things relating to calculating this as part of a select.

Comment: Do you literally need the format as "hours and seconds"? Not the more-usual "hours, minutes, seconds"?

Comment: Yes, sorry typo - that should have been minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers are generally correct with respect to converting the dates to milliseconds in epoch time, subtracting those, and converting the result back from milliseconds into your required units (although the specific implementations offered elsewhere do not currently give you exactly what you asked for -- i.e., just the number of minutes and seconds between your two datetimes).

However, please also note...

> new Date('2012-10-07 12:42:13')

... that this is not a reliable way to construct the Date from your SQLite date strings.

When you feed a string into the constructor of a Date object, you are effectively calling `Date.parse()`.  That behaves differently on different browsers.

Check this out:

```
> new Date('1-1-2012');
Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

> new Date('01-01-2012');
Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

> new Date('2012-1-1');
Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Looks pretty good, right? But that's on Chrome.

Now check out what happens in an up-to-date version of Firefox, with the exact same calls:

```
> new Date('1-1-2012');
Date {Invalid Date}

> new Date('01-01-2012');
Date {Invalid Date}

> new Date('2012-1-1');
Date {Invalid Date}

> new Date('2012-01-01');
Date {Sat Dec 31 2011 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)}
```

Furthermore, look at this behavior, in both browsers:

```
> new Date('2012-01-01');
Sat Dec 31 2011 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Simply prepending zeroes to the month and date digits causes a time warp!  You have to set the time and a timezone (for me, PST) to make that go away:

```
> new Date('2012-01-01T00:00:00-08:00')
Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Basically, dealing with date string parsing is a headache.  You don't want to have to digest and account for specs like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14), and [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

So, **here's a better alternative** -- pass the parts of your datetime as separate args to the constructor of the Date object.  That will reliably create the date for you, so your subsequent comparisons are valid.

> new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])

Here's what that initialization could look like for your case:

```
// Extract month, day, year from SQLite format, 'trimming' whitespace.
var sqlLiteSampleStr = "2012-10-07 11:01:13";
var re = /^\s*(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\s*$/;
var match = re.exec(sqlLiteSampleStr);
if (match) {
  var year = parseInt(match[1]);
  var month = parseInt(match[2]) - 1; // Zero-indexed months.
  var date = parseInt(match[3]);
  var hour = parseInt(match[4]);
  var minute = parseInt(match[5]);
  var second = parseInt(match[6]);
  var date = new Date(year, month, date, hour, minute, second);
}
```

Note: be careful of timezone considerations. You don't seem to have any timezone data in that SQLite format snippet.

**Update**

@james-j clarified that he's looking for minutes and seconds specifically.

Here's a snippet to extract just minutes and seconds:

```
var msPerMin = 1000 * 60;
var min = Math.floor(timeInMs / msPerMin);
var timeInMs = timeInMs - (min * msPerMin);
var sec = Math.floor(timeInMs / 1000 );
```

Comment: Thank you for a very indepth answer.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the strings to a JS `Date` Object, subtract the dates, and use some aritmethic to calculate hours/seconds from the result. Something like:

```
function convertMS(ms) {
  var d, h, m, s, ts, tm, th;
  s = ts = Math.floor(ms / 1000);
  m = tm = Math.floor(s / 60);
  s = s % 60;
  h = th = Math.floor(m / 60);
  m = m % 60;
  d = Math.floor(h / 24);
  h = h % 24;
  return { d: d, h: h, m: m, s: s, tm: tm, th: th, ts: ts};
};
var start = new Date('2012-10-07 11:01:13'.split('-').join('/'))
   ,end   = new Date('2012-10-07 12:42:13'.split('-').join('/'))
   ,dif   = convertMS(end - start);
console.log(dif.h+':'+dif.m);​​​​​​ //=> ​1:41
console.log('total minutes dif: '+dif.tm);​​​​​​ //=> total ​minutes dif: 101
console.log('total seconds dif: '+dif.ts);​​​​​​ //=> ​total seconds dif: 6060
```

[**edit** based on comment]
'Manual' parsing of a date string in the provided format:

```
Date.tryParse = function(ds){
  var  arr =  ds.match(/\d+/g)
      ,err = 'Expected at least yyyy'
      ,dat = arr.length && String(arr[0]).length === 4
              ? doParse.apply(null,arr) : err;
  return dat;

  function doParse(y,m,d,h,mi,s,ms){
   var dat = new Date(+y,(+m-1)||0,+d||1,+h||0,+mi||0,+s||0,+ms||0);
   return isNaN(dat) ? new Date : dat;
  }
}
var start = Date.tryParse('2012-10-07 11:01:13'); //=> Sun Oct 07 2012 11:01:13
var test  = Date.tryParse('2009');                //=> Sun Jan 01 2009 00:00:00
```

Comment: The OP's date string isn't compliant with the format specified for [Date.parse](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15) in ES5. Much better to parse the string manually.

Comment: iiuc, the OP is asking for the total delta converted into minutes and seconds, not just the minutes and seconds parts of the delta after being converted into days, hours, minutes, and seconds, which is what your answer is offering at the moment. In other words, if two times are 3 days, 8 hours, 3 minutes, and 15 seconds apart, your snippet will give him "3 minutes and 15 seconds" as the delta.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the detailed answers. Since this seems the most in depth and details I've started adding this to my code for testing. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct, however browsers do not consistently parse date strings (see below) so you should manually parse the strings. The format in the OP is not consistent with the format in ES5 either, and will not be correctly parsed by some browsers. A simple function to convert the OP format to a date that will work in all browsers is:

```
function stringToDate(s) { 
    s = s.split(/[-\/\. :]/);
    return new Date(s[0], --s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], 0)
}
```

There are some formats that are parsed by all browsers, however they are not standards compliant and if used, are dependent on all implementations continuing to support unspecified formats.

#### Edit

To tolerate malformed input (extra whitespace, different seperators, extra characters), `match` can be used instead of `split`:

```
function stringToDate(s) { 
    s = s.match(/\d+/g);
    return new Date(s[0], --s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], 0)
}
```

However, since the values are coming from a database and a format has been specified, the date strings should fit the format. Erroneous data should not be stored in the first place.

For completeness, here's a function to do what you want:

```
/*  Return difference between two dates as minutes and seconds mm:ss.
 *  Input format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
 *  If strings don't converted to dates (incorrect format or invalid values),
 *  return undefined.
 */
function diffInMins(s0, s1) {
  var diff;

  // Convert strings to date ojbects
  var d0 = stringToDate(s0);
  var d1 = stringToDate(s1);

  // Helper function to padd with leading zero
  function z(n) {
    return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;
  }

  // Check conversions
  if (d0 && d1 && typeof d0 == 'object' && typeof d1 == 'object') {

    // Return difference formatted as mm:ss
    if (d0 && d1) {
      diff = d1 - d0;
      return z(diff/60000 | 0) + ':' + z(Math.round(diff%60000/1000));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This example is a bit off. If there is leading whitespace, there will be extra elements in the split array, throwing off the resulting date value. There is also an off-by-one in the month value (zero-indexed months).

Comment: @manzoid—of course you need to pre-process user input to check the format, remove extra white space and so on, that takes one line of code and must be done howvever you intend to parse the string. The month index is accounted for, note `--s[1]`.

Comment: Yep, just minor nits because it is good to show robust solutions.  Good edits on your part in response to various comments. and you're right, you had the -- operator in there. Again in the interest of robustness maybe easier to read if expressed as '- 1'. Similar readability note-- maybe better to avoid the bitwise or for casting to number in favor of a more self-describing technique. Anyway, the OP should upvote multiple of these thoughtful answers but I will start by upvoting yours. Cheers--

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript actually makes subtracting dates quite simple. Here's how it works:

```
// Create Date objects from the strings
startDate = new Date('2012-10-07 11:01:13');
endDate = new Date('2012-10-07 12:42:13');

// Subtract Date objects to return milliseconds between them
millisecondsBetween = (endDate - startDate);

// Convert to whatever you like
alert(millisecondsBetween/1000/60 + ' minutes');
```